# swagger/swashbuckle Ui fields for List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm using swagger 5.6.3 in .net 5 web API application

In a controller, I use a DTO object

```
   [HttpPost]
   public void create([FromForm] CDTO data)
```

CDTO:

```
public class CDTO
{
    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string descrption { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> data { get; set; }
}
```

swagger UI for KeyValuePair<string, string> as follow:
[image]

but for IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> as follow:
[image]

and not correctly deserialized. have a solution to show list items as key-values?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are asking, however I created web API .NET 5. referenced newtonsoft.Json. Changed the required attributes on the CDTO to be as follows:

```
public class CDTO
{
    [JsonRequired]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [JsonRequired]
    public string descrption { get; set; }
   [JsonRequired]
    public IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> data { get; set; }
}
```

Then started up the app and submitted :

[image]

Comment: thank you Richard for your answer 
I want to show  Key-input and value-input and use AddItem-button for next